# My ftp account does not show up in filezilla?

Tags: ftp, filezilla, web-hosting

## Context

I use zpanel to manage my FTP accounts. I have deleted the one I was using and created a new one.

## Problem

When I connect to my server using Filezilla, I can't find the new ftp directory, instead it still shows me the previous directory.
When I try to delete it, it says permission denied.

## Question

How do I access the files of the new account?